# Delphi: How to create an extra design-time menu for a custom component?

Tags: delphi, menu, ide, delphi-xe2

I've recently recompiled TDBGrid component, to implement several custom functions, altho i've noticed that the feature of extra design-time context menu item "Columns editor" is gone now.

[image: http://i121.photobucket.com/albums/o210/R33_m/Columns.png]

I've failed to find any code which creates this menu in original `Vcl.DBGrids` unit and had a really bad luck looking for a solution online on how to do this.

This also applies to double-clicking. It used to call Columns Editor, now it just creates OnCellClick event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your design time package for the component, implement a component editor:

```
type
  TMyComponentEditor = class(TComponentEditor)
    procedure ExecuteVerb(Index: Integer); override;
    function GetVerb(Index: Integer): string; override;
    function GetVerbCount: Integer; override;
  end;

procedure TMyComponentEditor.ExecuteVerb(Index: Integer);
begin
  case Index of
  0:
    Beep;
  end;
end;

function TMyComponentEditor.GetVerb(Index: Integer): string;
begin
  Result := 'Beep';
end;

function TMyComponentEditor.GetVerbCount: Integer;
begin
  Result := 1;
end;
```

You need to register this component editor also. Call `RegisterComponentEditor` in your `Register` procedure to do so:

```
RegisterComponentEditor(TMyComponent, TMyComponentEditor);
```

Comment: @Uli I'd guess that would be difficult since there is no source for it.

Comment: http://www.codeforge.com/read/158059/CMoneyDBGridEd6.pas__html
This link helped me create Columns editor.
Not sure if it's original code or not, but it works pretty good so far. In case someone else will look for it.